# Table seating question for real life use!

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out how to rotate 75 people between 10 tables for 3 rotations with the people not overlapping when they rotate. Goal: for the attendess to meet new people at each table rotation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing it entirely randomly (write the names on cards and shuffle them, or do basically the same thing in a computer program, like excel or python). I'm pretty certain it won't take many attempts to get it right.

Comment: Any idea what formula to use for an Excel spreadsheet like you suggest?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy formula for this. You'll have to actually _do_ it: write down all the names (or just give them numbers, that's easier), and make three random seatings, and check that that no two people (or numbers) sit together twice. What I would do is to just let the first seating be 1-7 together, 8-15 together, and so on. Then make random second seatings until those work, then make random third seatings until they work. And after that I would assign names to the numbers and figure out who actually sits where when.

Comment: I tried that last year for this same event and it worked (for the most part, there were a few overlaps) but it took HOURS so I was hoping there would be another option out there

Comment: Excel does make the shuffling and checking for each attempt take seconds rather than minutes, though. After initial setup at least.

Comment: What exactly is an overlap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate n individuals at a dinner party so that every guest meets every other guests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/how-to-rotate-n-individuals-at-a-dinner-party-so-that-every-guest-meets-every-ot)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Please do not just close every question that involves people meeting with each other as a duplicate of that problem. They are not duplicates, so you are not helping anyone.

Comment: Sorry. It was my honest mistake, I have hence retracted all of them @MikeEarnest

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Thanks you for that, I'm sorry I responded so harshly. I get passionate about these sorts of questions, I suppose, haha. You did the right thing and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

**For 81 guests**

A neat way without requiring calculation is to arrange 81 names (or numbers) in a 9x9 grid.

The tables for one arrangement are given by the rows.

The tables for the next arrangement are given by the columns.

The tables for the final arrangement are given by diagonals (wrapping around as if a tube has been formed by glueing together the top and bottom edges).

**For 75 guests**

Simply ignore 6 of the 'people'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1    11    21    31    41    51    61    71
 2    12    22    32    42    52    62    72
 3    13    23    33    43    53    63    73
 4    14    24    34    44    54    64    74
 5    15    25    35    45    55    65    75
 6    16    26    36    46    56    66    76
 7    17    27    37    47    57    67    77
 8    18    28    38    48    58    68    78
 9    19    29    39    49    59    69    79
10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80

 1    12    23    34    45    56    67    78
 2    13    24    35    46    57    68    79
 3    14    25    36    47    58    69    80
 4    15    26    37    48    59    70    71
 5    16    27    38    49    60    61    72
 6    17    28    39    50    51    62    73
 7    18    29    40    41    52    63    74
 8    19    30    31    42    53    64    75
 9    20    21    32    43    54    65    76
10    11    22    33    44    55    66    77

 1     2    25    26    49    50    63    64
13    14    37    38    51    52    75    76
 3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
11    12    15    16    17    18    19    20
21    22    23    24    27    28    29    30
31    32    33    34    35    36    39    40
41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
61    62    65    66    67    68    69    70
71    72    73    74    77    78    79    80
```

Then, if there are fewer people, these absences won't
cause a table of six:

```
 1   3  15  22  38  39  46  54
```