# What's a solution for having a group of people meet each other exactly once, even if there is an odd number of people?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is this: I would like in a group of people to easily arrange and move them around such that every pair comes together exactly once, without any repetitions. I'm looking for all combinations, not all permutations. This should work for both even and odd numbers of people.

I'm looking for a solution that works physically for a group, such that people can be moved around in a consistent way - not a way to generate a list of all combinations.

I have read the solution in the below linked thread, but having experimented with this in a spreadsheet, I can only make it work for an even number of people.

I didn't comment on that thread because I'm new here and I'm not allowed to yet. I would deeply appreciate any help.

[How to rotate n individuals at a dinner party so that every guest meets every other guests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/how-to-rotate-n-individuals-at-a-dinner-party-so-that-every-guest-meets-every-ot/34336#34336?newreg=17aed7ccb8074a58b94e0884f52e97cf)

Comment: You say combinations not permutations, but it is not clear to me what sort of conditions there are in terms of when someone is considered as having "met" another person... In the linked question it was very clearly that a person is considered as having "met" another person if there was a point in time that they were sitting adjacent to each other.  How is it in your case?  A person as having met if they were put in the same group as one another?  Why not just make one huge group at the start with everyone in it and be done with it then and there.

Comment: If you're talking about pairs of people, what do you do with the odd person out?  Does everyone except the odd person out need to be in a pair?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I would like each person to be considered to have 'met' the other person if they have been opposite them for one cycle (not adjacent to them).

Comment: And if it's an odd number there will always been 1 person left out each cycle. I'm looking to get through all possible pair combinations without repeating, knowing that each time someone will be left out of the pairs (I'm guessing each person gets left out once but not sure about that).

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thank you. You are correct, that one is the solution I was looking for. Thank you everyone, and I apologize for the duplication - I searched earlier and must have missed on the best search terms to use.