# Algorithm for grouping elements multiple times without two elements being in the same group.

Tags: permutations, algorithms

I have the following set:
I have a total of $N=45$ elements in my set, $26$ "$e$" elements, and $19$ "$s$" elements
$$
{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_{26},s_1, s_2, \dots, s_{19}}
$$
I now want to find an algorithm for listing permutations of special groupings of these elements. The rules for the groupings in each permutation are as follows:

Each permutation consists of 9 groups. 8 which look like this:
$$\{e,e,e;s,s\}$$
and one which looks like this:
$$\{s,s,s,e,e\}$$

where "e" and "s" here denotes that these elements of the set have to be of the "e" or "s" type. An example of such a permutation would look like this:
$$
\{e_1,e_2,e_3,s_1,s_2\},\{e_4,e_5,e_6,s_3,s_4\},\dots,\{e_{22},e_{23},e_{24},s_{15},s_{16}\}
$$
$$
\{e_{25},e_{26},s_{17},s_{18},s_{19}\}
$$
I now want to find an algorithm, which systematically gives me such permutations, until each element has been at least once together in a group of 5 (9 of which make up a permutation) with each other element. I want to achieve this in as few permutations as possible, so as long as it is possible I want to avoid permutations grouping elements together in the same group again, if this has already happened in a previous permutation.

Does anyone have any clever ideas on how such an algorithm could look like or can point me in the right direction on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: What is the origin of this question?

Comment: [1] When you say "avoid...grouping elements in the same group again" do you mean that repetition of the  group $e_1, e_2, e_3, s_1, s_2$ should be avoided,  or even that of  a sub group eg $e_1 ,e_2, e_3, s_2, s_4$ should be avoided [2] Does your question relate to some actual grouping problem ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin It was a problem given to me by a friend working in a law firm. They have certain employees called EPs and SPs (hence the e and s) and are arranging focus group meetings with the setup 3EPs and 2SPs. Then since the numbers don't neatly work for having all groups like that, one group will be 3SPs and 2EPs. They want everyone to be in a group with everybode else at least once and want the least amount of meetings and want to basically figure out how to best arrage that.

Comment: @trueblueanil I mean even the subgroups should be avoided. See my prvious comment, the goal is to have every element be together with every other element at least once in as few permutations as possible. I don't know if this maps to some known grouping problem already. I searched online, but couldn't find anything that applies. I was hoping someone on here might know.

Comment: To be clear, each of the $45$ elements must be with each of the remaining $44$ at least once in one or other of the $9$ groups of $5$

Comment: @trueblueanil I'm not sure what you mean by "one or other", but to reformulate it. Each of the 45 elements must be with each of the remaining 44 at least once in a group of 5. So if you imagine that each permutation is meeting of all of the 45 people (i.e. elements), and thre are nine tables in each meeting with 5 people sitting at each table. Then each person must have shared a table at least once with each other person. I hope that clears it up, but let me know if it's still unclear! Thanks for the interest in the question!

Comment: You can have a look here, and see if it helps. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/how-to-rotate-n-individuals-at-a-dinner-party-so-that-every-guest-meets-every-ot?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @trueblueanil interesting, it seems very similar, I'll take a look, thanks!!